# How can i exclude subdomain(cdn.domain.com) from 301 redirection in my .htaccess?

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using following rule in my .htaccess file to enforce https version

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This works fine however,  i have   https://cdn.domain.com to serve assets from cdn service(amazon)
this subdomain also redirects to   https://www  version  which i dont want.    Can i exclude   https://cdn.domain.com from this rule?

I tried to put this one  but did not work:   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=cdn.domain.com [NC]`   could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```